# Space between two elements

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to coding. I'm playing around with a page where I have the nav bar at the very top of the page. Directly underneath I'm wanting an image with the page logo and description on top of the image.

The problem I'm having is there is a blank space between the nav bar and the image.

If I delete the words from the header (the logo, description) the image becomes flush with the nav bar like I intend it to be. But if put the words back into the header the space separates my two elements again. I'm not sure why this is consider the words are with the larger container of the header.

Can anyone help me delete this space between the elements.

By the way, this is my first time posting a question, so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Below are my html and css codes. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class='top-bar'>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Destinations</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Languages</a></li>
        <li><a href='project1-about.html'>About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<header>
<h1><span>Project 1</span></h1>
<p class='kicker'>Traveling // Exploring // Coding</p>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    height: 450px;
    background: url('http://gratisography.com/pictures/17_1.jpg') center center; 
    background-size: cover; 
    margin: 0; }

header p {
    font-family: Cinzel; }


.top-bar  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0; }


nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 30px 0 0;
    height: 50px; }

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase; }

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Cinzel; }

 nav a:hover {
    color: grey; }

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: Cinzel;
    weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05em; 
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 100px; }


.kicker {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative; }

span  {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    border: white solid 10px; }
```

Comment: From title, I am 99% sure you are talking about space because of inline block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have not done the [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/). Your H1 tags and other elements still have the browser default CSS properties like margin and paddings which is causing this behaviour.

Fix:

```
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8yaxmj11/).

Comment: This sorted out the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

i have added  margin-top: 0 to h1 .

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-family: Cinzel;
    weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0` in your `h1` tag.In Markup, `h1` tag take its default `margin` , so when you reset your **css** then it should be worked.Take a look in **[JSFIDDLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/pnhck5tu/2/)**

```css
header {
  height: 450px;
  background: url('http://gratisography.com/pictures/17_1.jpg') center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
header p {
  font-family: Cinzel;
}
.top-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 30px 0 0;
  height: 50px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Cinzel;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: Cinzel;
  weight: 700;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin: 0
}
.kicker {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  border: white solid 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='top-bar'>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Destinations</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Languages</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='project1-about.html'>About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<header>
  <h1><span>Project 1</span></h1>
  <p class='kicker'>Traveling // Exploring // Coding</p>
</header>
```